# Meaning of LC_IDENTIFICATION environment variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, environment-variables, locale

Just out of curiosity, what is the meaning of `LC_IDENTIFICATION`?

The reason I am asking is, that a fresh US-English installation of Linux Mint (I guess Ubuntu would be the same), located in “Jerusalem” for time zone, left me with the following mix and match locale in `/etc/default/locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=he_IL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=he_IL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=he_IL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=he_IL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=he_IL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=he_IL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=he_IL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=he_IL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=he_IL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

As I was working to fix it to my liking, I was wondering if I should also update `LC_IDENTIFICATION`.

The `man` page for `locale(1)` says “Metadata about the locale information”, but it does not tell me exactly what the effect of changing it would be. Can you think of any application or API using this variable and how?

Comment: "LC_IDENTIFICATION= may be used to override the locale settings at boot" https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/locale.conf.html

Comment: @sr9yar from the link you refer to, read the entire sentence again: “Note that the kernel command line options [… a list of all possible locale.*= options …] may be used to override the locale settings at boot.” It doesn’t say anything about the meaning of those settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that by setting `LC_IDENTIFICATION` you indeed supply metadata for a given locale specification, as seen in [this example of the Uzbekistan locale](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=4336&action=view):

```
LC_IDENTIFICATION
title      "Uzbek (latin) locale for Uzbekistan"
source     "Bobir Ismailov"
address    ""
contact    "Bobir Ismailov, Pablo Saratxaga, Mashrab Kuvatov"
email      "bobir_is@yahoo.com, pablo@mandrakesoft.com, kmashrab@uni-bremen.de"
tel        ""
fax        ""
language   "Uzbek"
territory  "Uzbekistan"
revision   "0.5"
date       "2003-06-27"
```

Or another variant with [the Greek locale](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-glibc/2001-11/msg00015.html):

```
LC_IDENTIFICATION
title      "Greek locale for Greece"
source     "RAP"
address    "Sankt Jorgens Alle 8, DK-1615 Kobenhavn V, Danmark"
contact    ""
email      "address@hidden"
tel        ""
fax        ""
language   "Greek"
territory  "Greece"
revision   "1.0"
date       "2000-06-29"
```

`LC_IDENTIFICATION` [is a GNU extension](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Special-Shell-Variables.html). I could not find a specification of it though. Since it's just metadata, I'm assuming it's not used in any userland programs.

Comment: Actually, [lightdm uses it](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lightdm-team/lightdm/trunk/view/2455/liblightdm-gobject/language.c) when available for displaying the current language in the status bar.

Comment: > 
It contains information about the locale itself and is rarely useful for users or developers  [https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Locales](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Locales)